# SQL connection string for embedded database in Visual Studio solution

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am starting with SQL Server in Visual Studio and have a problem, most probably with my connection string.

I am not installing SQL Server on my computer (there are several reasons for that) but created inside my solution a SQL project. Then, in another project I am attempting to connect to this database using some googled examples, but can't manage to connect. I frequently see that there's a user and password used to connect to the db, but in my case, thus there is no installation but an embedded SQL project, I can't work it out...

My connection string looks like this:

```
sqlConnectionString = @"Data Source = MyComputerName;initial catalog=DatabaseStudents";
```

Can anyone let me know if this kind of installation is even possible?

Thanks

Comment: **SQL** is just a query language - **not** a product that you can install on your PC (or leave off). You should really tell us what **concrete RDBMS** you're using - and add a relevant tag for this  to your question!

Comment: if you are using an .mdf file the connection string should look like something like `connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|EmbeddedDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`

Comment: Also depending on the DB, the connector makes a huge difference as well :)

Comment: @marc thanks, I will use MsSql

Comment: Do NOT use LOCAL DB like styx suggested it is wrong a probably will not work.Localdb you are directly connecting to an MDF file which is the wrong approach.  You have a credential issue.The MDF file as attached to the database and you want to access the MDF file through the server.I would open SQL Server Managements Studio and check in login window that you have Windows Credential.The login window will show the server name and instance of the database.Your connection string needs both the Server Name and Instance.  Also need Trusted_Connection=True;https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: @styx i am trying to connect through code in my first approach, basing on `www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-using-dapper-in-c-sharp/`

Comment: @jdweng Can I use a connectionstring to connect to a database created as a project in VisualStudio, without having installed on my computer SQL Server Managements Studio (or any others)?

Comment: If you want to use SQL Server on your machine - you **must** install at least some form of SQL Server locally. The only way you can avoid installing SQL Server locally is when you connect to a **remote** instance of SQL Server on another machine / server for all your work. SQL Server is **not** an "embedded" database system...

Comment: If you have installed the ".NET Desktop Development" workload in Visual Studio, you have SQL Server Express LocalDB installed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @marc_s I see... thanks on this!

Comment: The database should be attached to a SQL Server on a remote machine so Windows Credentials are used.  The Net Library drivers will allow you to connect to the remove machine without having a local SQL Server installed.  You can install SQL Server Management Studio without installing the entire SQL Server on remote machines which is nice for debugging issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be in your web.config if you're looking for a simple answer

```
<add name="YourDBContext" 
   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFile.mdf" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Thanks, i finally manged to connect (1) installing `https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads`, and (2) using `string sqlConnectionString = @"server =MyComputerName\SQLEXPRESS;database=MyDatabaseName;Integrated Security=true;";`